# Saving long form data to database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, csv

I have a form that is populated by a CSV file, always 229 fields but anywhere up to 10 or 12 rows. The form populates correctly, but I'm having issues saving it all. The loop seems like it's missing something or maybe something is mismatched.

Here is the form code:

**page-confirm.php**

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $db);

if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
    //echo'success!';
}

if(isset($_POST['preview']))
{
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);


$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$maxPreviewRows = PHP_INT_MAX;  // this will be ~2 billion on 32-bit system, or ~9 quintillion on 64-bit system
$hasHeaderRow = true;
    echo "<form method='post' action='/form-submit' >";
    echo '<table>';

    if ($hasHeaderRow) {
        $headerRow = fgetcsv($handle);
        echo '<thead><tr>';
        foreach($headerRow as $value) {
            echo "<th>$value</th>";
        }
        echo '</tr></thead>';
    }

    echo '<tbody>';

    $rowCount = 0;
    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        $colCount = 0;
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $value) {
            echo "<td><input name='row[".$rowCount."][".$colCount."]' type='text' value='$value' /></td>";

                $colCount++;
                } 
        echo '</tr>';

        if (++$rowCount > $maxPreviewRows) {
            break;
        }
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
    echo "<input type='submit' name='confirm' value='confirm'>";
    echo '</form>';
    }
    ?>
```

Here's the code for the submission page with the insert loop:

**page-formsubmit.php**

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $db);



if ($connect->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
}else{
echo'success!';
}

//var_dump($_POST);


$sql = $inserts = $binds = [];
foreach ($_POST['row'] as $rowValue){
if(is_array($rowValue) && count($rowValue) > 0 ){
    foreach($rowValue as $rowData){
       /***
        * Stupidly, I had missed that row contains arrays 
        * rather than values, so you need a foreach, inside the 
        * foreach as so:
        ***/
        foreach ($rowData as $columnKey  => $columnValue){
            //$columnValue will now equal $value
            //$columnKey will be the column number (1...229)
            /***
             * This is the area you can construct your SQL query values.
             * db_connection is assumed to be setup.
             ***/
             $sql[] = "`column_name_".$columnKey."`";
             $binder = "value".$columnKey;
             $inserts[] = ":".$binder;
             $binds[$binder] = $columnValue;
             unset($binder);
        }
       unset($columnKey,$columnValue);             
   }
   unset($rowData);
   /***
    * This is the area the SQL query is set on a per row basis
    ***/
   $sqlFull = "INSERT INTO staging (".implode(",",$sql).") VALUES(".implode(",",$inserts).")";
   $connect->prepare($sqlFull); 
   /***
    * EDIT: bind param MUST come after the prepare call
    ***/
   foreach($binds as $bindKey=>$bindRow){
        $connect->bind_param(":".$bindKey, $bindRow);
   }
   unset($bindKey,$bindRow);
   var_dump($binds);      
   $sql = $inserts = $binds = []; //reset arrays for next row iteration. 
   /***
    * db_connection then executes the statement constructed above
    ***/
    $connect->execute();
 } //close if.
}
unset($rowValue);

?>
```

You can see in the submission page where I comment out the var_dump for post data. When it's active, it prints out this for the array:

```
success!array(1) { ["row"]=> array(5) { [0]=> array(229)
```

and continues printing the 229 elements for all 7 rows.

There is something that's not quite working in this loop because even a debug statement within the loop to print the query won't work. I just need to make sure it iterates all 229 fields of every row to the end of the form and puts them into my staging table.

My staging table, which is temporary, has 229 named fields in the exact order as the CSV, so I shouldn't have to declare each field I don't believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are hitting the PHP configuration default maximum number of input variables. In your `php.ini` you will need to set `max_input_vars` directive to something greater than the default of 1000.

```
max_input_vars = 3000
```

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

To fix the issue with entering the data into the database, you will need to fix a bunch of errors. I have simply rewritten the "page-formsubmit.php" like so...

**page-formsubmit.php**

```
/**
 * This requires the use of PHP 5.6 or greater. Older versions are not supported
 */
$connect = mysqli_connect( $server, $user, $pw, $db );

if( $connect->connect_error ) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
} else 
{
    echo'success!';
}

//var_dump($_POST);

foreach ($_POST['row'] as $rowValue)
{
    if( is_array($rowValue) && count($rowValue) > 0 )
    {
        $sqlFull = "INSERT INTO staging VALUES( DEFAULT, ". substr( str_repeat ( '?, ', count($rowValue) ), 0, -2 ) .")";
        if( !$stmt = $connect->prepare($sqlFull) )
        {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $connect->errno . ") " . $connect->error;
        }
        $stmt->bind_param( str_repeat ( 's', count($rowValue) ), ...$rowValue );

        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: so would I change that on my hosting service?

Comment: Yes, it is a server level configuration.

Comment: Ok just changed it to 3000 in the ini file. Now, when I submit the form, I have it print arrays and don't seem to be running into any issues there but it's still not submitting to the database

Comment: Ok, I pasted my column names into the first parenthesis of the INSERT statement but still nothing in the database. I've been completely stuck on this for a few days now and I'm just not sure where the issue is exactly.

Comment: Try adding `printf( "Error: %s\n", $connect->error );` after `$connect->execute();` to see what is going on.

Comment: It doesn't print anything at all there, it just shows my connect succes message which is above the sql code as you can see in the first block of code above. However, if I move my connection loop under the sql code it won't print that either

Comment: @TomN. I have included additional code to address the DB issue.

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting somewhere now. I get this error: Prepare failed: (1136) Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I think it's because I forgot that the CSV has 229 columns but the db table has 230

Comment: Is there something in the statement that is affected by that? In other words, the fact that the column count in the db table is one more than the column count of the CSV/Form

Comment: Yes, the SQL statement is assuming there will be the same number of fields based on your statement _"My staging table, which is temporary, has 229 named fields in the exact order as the CSV, so I shouldn't have to declare each field I don't believe."_  What is the extra field used for and where is it placed?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think about that and I just realized it. It's an auto-incrementing ID column

Comment: Changed it so that should work. Look for the line beginning with `$sqlFull = "INSERT INTO staging VALUES( DEFAULT, "`

Comment: Sorry, really quick. Is there something in the statement or code that you wrote that would cause for an ending or even an encoding issue where it would only insert the first 4 rows into the db? If I print_r the POST it displays [0] array through [4] array but only inserts 4 rows, and there are 7 in the form. I know it has to be something on that block because all 7 rows show up on the form.